# Gracefully terminating all the threads

Tags: multithreading, delphi, delphi-10.2-tokyo

I am using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16205470/multithread-queue-in-delphi) in one of my solution

My requirement is to clear the queue and kill all the threads gracefully when Stop button is clicked.

For this I created an `ObjectList`

```
var
  List: TObjectList<TMyConsumerItem>;
begin
  { Create a new List. }
  List := TObjectList<TMyConsumerItem>.Create();
```

Later I made this modification:

```
procedure TForm1.DoSomeJob(myListItems: TStringList);
...
for i := 1 to cThreadCount do
    List.Add(TMyConsumerItem.Create(aQueue, aCounter));
```

And on Stop button button click I am doing this

```
for i := 0 to List.Count - 1 do
  begin
    List.Item[i].Terminate;
  end;
  aCounter.Free;
  aQueue.Free;
```

While doing this I application is getting hanged. Is this the correct approach or am I missing something?

I am using 10.2 Tokyo

**Edit 1:**

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants,
  System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, Vcl.StdCtrls;

type

  TMyConsumerItem = class(TThread)
  private
    FQueue : TThreadedQueue<TProc>;
    FSignal : TCountDownEvent; 
  protected
    procedure Execute; override;
  public
    constructor Create( aQueue : TThreadedQueue<TProc>; aSignal : TCountdownEvent);
  end;


  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Button1: TButton;
    Memo1: TMemo;
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
    procedure StopClick(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
    List: TObjectList<TMyConsumerItem>;
    aQueue: TThreadedQueue<TProc>;
    aCounter: TCountDownEvent;
    procedure DoSomeJob( myListItems : TStringList);
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

uses
  SyncObjs, Generics.Collections;

{- Include TMyConsumerItem class here }

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  aList : TStringList;
  i : Integer;
begin
  aList := TStringList.Create;
  Screen.Cursor := crHourGlass;
  try
    for i := 1 to 20 do aList.Add(IntToStr(i));
    DoSomeJob(aList);
  finally
    aList.Free;
    Screen.Cursor := crDefault;
  end;
end;

procedure TForm1.StopClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  for i := 0 to List.Count - 1 do
  begin
    List.Item[i].Terminate;
  end;
  List.Free;
  aCounter.WaitFor;
  aCounter.Free;
  aQueue.Free;
end;

procedure TForm1.DoSomeJob(myListItems: TStringList);
const
  cThreadCount = 10;
  cMyQueueDepth = 100;
var
  i: Integer;

  function CaptureJob(const aString: string): TProc;
  begin
    Result :=
      procedure
      var
        i,j : Integer;
      begin
        // Do some job with aString
        for i := 0 to 1000000 do
          j := i;
        // Report status to main thread
        TThread.Synchronize(nil,
          procedure
          begin
            Memo1.Lines.Add('Job with:'+aString+' done.');
          end
        );

      end;
  end;
var
  aThread : TThread;
begin
  List := TObjectList<TMyConsumerItem>.Create();
  List.OwnsObjects := False;
  aQueue := TThreadedQueue<TProc>.Create(cMyQueueDepth);
  aCounter := TCountDownEvent.Create(cThreadCount);
  try
    for i := 1 to cThreadCount do
       List.Add(TMyConsumerItem.Create(aQueue, aCounter));
    for i := 0 to myListItems.Count - 1 do
    begin
      aQueue.PushItem(CaptureJob(myListItems[i]));
    end;
  finally

  end;
end;


constructor TMyConsumerItem.Create(aQueue: TThreadedQueue<TProc>; aSignal : TCountDownEvent);
begin
 Inherited Create(false);
 Self.FreeOnTerminate := true;
 FQueue := aQueue;
 FSignal := aSignal;
end;

procedure TMyConsumerItem.Execute;
var
aProc : TProc;
begin
 try
 repeat
  FQueue.PopItem(aProc);
  aProc();
 until Terminated;
 finally
  FSignal.Signal;
 end;
end;
end.
```

Comment: Why are not you using TTask?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You left out some important stuff regarding how the job queue works and how to interact with the threadpool.

1. Taking a reference to a thread that is self-terminating is wrong. Remove the `List`, since it is useless.
2. In order to finish the queue at a later point, make `aQueue` global.
3. To finish the threadpool, add as many empty tasks to the queue as there are threads.
4. See example below how a stop method could be implemented. Note that both `aCounter` and `aQueue` must be global in scope. Disclaimer untested, not in front of a compiler at the moment.
5. If you need to abort ongoing work in the job tasks, you will have to provide a reference to a global (in scope) flag with each job task, and signal to end the task.
6. There are other libraries that can perform similar work, see [Delphi PPL](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Seattle/en/Using_the_Parallel_Programming_Library) or the well proven [OTL library](http://www.omnithreadlibrary.com/).

---

```
procedure TForm1.StopClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  i : Integer;
  aThread : TThread;
begin
  // Kill the worker threads by pushing nil
  for i := 1 to cThreadCount do
    aQueue.PushItem(nil);

  // Since the worker threads synchronizes with the main thread,
  // we must wait for them in another thread.
  aThread := TThread.CreateAnonymousThread(
    procedure
    begin
      aCounter.WaitFor; // Wait for threads to finish
      aCounter.Free;
      aQueue.Free;
    end
  );
  aThread.FreeOnTerminate := false;
  aThread.Start;
  aThread.WaitFor;  // Safe to wait for the anonymous thread
  aThread.Free;
end;
```

Comment: Thanks. I updated the question making aQueue global. So to abort the ongoing work can I place a global boolean variable, set that in Stop button click and break from Thread.Exceute when that boolean is set to true?

Comment: A global boolean set to true and checked regularly inside the job method to abort the job itself. You don't need to abort the thread, since feeding blank jobs into the queue will take care of that.

Answer (score 1):

`Terminate` only sets the `Terminated` property to true. It's important that the internal loop of the thread checks the `Terminated` property periodically, and returns from the `Execute` method when it is set to true. After that, use  `WaitFor` in the main thread to check the threads have all ended before you free queue or thread-pool objects.

Comment: Or define an `OnTerminate` event method that free the objects when the last thread executes. That will spare the application from having to actively wait for the threads to finish by using the call to `WaitFor`.

Comment: @Stijn Sanders - Yes I am checking for Terminated property in the Thread.Excecute. And doing WaitFor still hangs the application.

Comment: @LURD Yes I will try that. So to find the last thread should I use aCounter.CurrentCount = 1. Sorry the syntax might be wrong as I cannot acces my delphi system now

Comment: @Bharat, yes, increment a counter each time you create a new thread and decrement the counter in the `OnTerminate` event. When the counter is zero, free the objects and perhaps let the user know it's done in some way.

Comment: @LURD Thanks I understood and it helps. I will implement that. You can post your comment as an answer.

Comment: @Bharat, I see now that you are using one of my exampels, where the job tasks are pushed into the queue and executed by a threadpool. From your code, I'm having a hard time to see the purpose of using `aQueue` and `aCounter` together with the `TObjectList`. You should not have a reference to the `TMyConsumerItem`. Instead push as many empty tasks to the queue as there are threads in the pool. If you want to end the tasks before their job is finished, you will have to include a semaphore for that.

Comment: @LURD Yes I am using your example and pushing empty tasks to the queue. I thought that terminating the threads will do my job but should I consider semaphore here?